# Задача на проверку последовательности

Tags: c++, массивы, арифметика

Я не могу понять что не так с кодом, можете помочь дописать его

Вот задача: Ввести с клавиатуры целое число n и ввести n натуральных чисел. Выяснить, является ли последовательность этих чисел такой, в которой двухзначные и трехзначные числа идут по очереди. Например, для последовательностей 34 678 12 897 23 или 674 12 567 43 ответ будет «Да».

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
    const int MAX = 100;
    int n, i, c, a, v;
    int z[MAX];
    cout << "Введите целое число ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Введите " << n << " натуральных чисел\n";
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> c;
        z[i] = c;
    }
    for (a = 0; a <= i; ++a)
    {
        while (z[a])
        {
            z[a] /= 10;
        }
    }
    for (v = 0; v < a; ++v)
    {
        if (z[v] == 2 || z[v] == 3)
        {
            cout << "да" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "нет" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вариант, как сделать Вам предложили, а что касается Вашего кода... Как минимум, Вы не то проверяете. **z[a] /= 10;** - не даст Вам количество цифр в числе, это вам даст сколько в числе десятков: 2 или 3, с учетом последующей проверки **if (z[v] == 2 || z[v] == 3)**

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Простите великодушно, но цикл `while (z[a])
        {
            z[a] /= 10;
        }` не даст вообще ничего, кроме обнуления `z[a]`...

Comment: @Harry Ой, да.... ступил, извиняюсь :))

Answer (score 1):

Что вы делаете тут - для меня вообще загадка... Обнулить массив `z` можно было и проще :)

```
for (a = 0; a <= i; ++a)
    {
        while (z[a])
        {
            z[a] /= 10;
        }
    }
```

И вообще - у вас решение из серии "зачем просто, если можно сложно?" :)

Устроит что-то вроде этого?

```
int digs(unsigned int a)
{
    if (a >= 1000) return 0;
    if (a >= 100) return 3;
    if (a >= 10) return 2;
    return 0;
}

/* Или даже
int digs(unsigned int a)
{
    return (a >= 1000) ? 0 : (a >= 100) ? 3 :
        (a >= 10) ? 2 : 0;
}
Можно, конечно, *вычислять* количество знаков, но зачем?...
*/

int main()
{
    unsigned int n, a;
    cin >> n >> a;
    int last = digs(a);
    if (last == 0) { cout << "No\n"; return 0; }
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> a;
        int curr = digs(a);
        if (curr == 0 || curr == last) { cout << "No\n"; return 0; }
        last = curr;
    }
    cout << "Yes\n";
}
```